# Where can I learn about Sheaves as an indepdendent topic?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, sheaf-theory

After I took point-set topology I read Steen and Seebach's Counter Examples in Topology and really appreciated learning about the creative topological spaces that people have thought up.

I wish there was a similiar book for sheaves. I understand that Sheaf Cohomology is a big thing these days, and that they appear a lot in algebraic geometry, but as of right now I want to learn more about the sheaves themselves and wish I had a gallery of interesting sheaves that people have thought up in the past. Sheaves have been around for awhile, and have been used in many parts of mathematics, so I'm sure that somewhere there exists a body of work about their intrinsinic properties as a topological and algebraic object.

However, I can't find it. Are there old papers somewhere somebody could link me to? And old textbook? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly are classic texts on sheaves and sheaf cohomology.  [Bredon](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387949055) and [Godement](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/2705612521) are two. Sheaves and sheaf cohomology are also treated in [Warner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387908943) and most ever book on complex manifolds.

Comment: I looked at Bredon's book and it's all about sheaf cohomology. Warner's book is where I've been reading about sheaves; he has a short section on sheaves and presheaves and then the rest of it is also about sheaf cohomology. I tried looking for the Godement book just now (you accidently linked me Brendon twice) but found no results. I found some old lecture notes online that look promising though.

Comment: Oops. I'll fix the Godement link. It is, however, in French. You're not going to find a "Counterexamples in Topology" sort of reference for sheaves. They're of interest because of the different ways Čech and sheaf cohomology show up all over mathematics, not for pursuing point-set topology anomalies.

Comment: Ah, French, luckily, Je Parle Francais. (It means I speak french, but actually thats the only thing that I know how to say LOL). 

Yeah, I mean sheaves have been around for quite some time and show up a lot, so I'm sure somewhere there's been people studying them for their intrinsic interest. I wish I could find those papers.